# How to change value of a variable in service and reflect it in a component that uses that service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need a small help. I've a component and a service. The component is relying upon a variable whose value depends upon another variable which is in a service. The variable (one which is in service) is initially `false` but it should become `true` after getting the response (I'm using some Observable-Subscribe code at this point to mimic an HTTP GET call). Now the same `true` value is not reflecting back in my component. That's the problem. Here is the code:

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>Current status: {{ status }}</h2>
<button (click)="onButtonPress()" >Click</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  status: boolean;
  constructor(private _myService: MyserviceService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.status = this._myService.serviceStatus;
  }
  onButtonPress() {
    this._myService.takeAction();
  }
}
```

**myservice.service.ts**

```
export class MyserviceService {
  serviceStatus: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
  }
  takeAction() {
    interval(1000)
    .pipe(take(5), toArray())
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.serviceStatus = true;
    });
  }
}
```

I've created one [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-75wqt6). Please have a look and feel free to point out mistakes in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to create BehaviorSubject variable in service, e.g.
serviceStatus = new BehaviourSubject(false); // default value is false
and in the takeAction method change value of serviceStatus variable to true, e.g.
this.serviceStatus.next(true);

In your app.component.ts in ngOnInit subscribe to serviceStatus variable, e.g.
this._myService.serviceStatus.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(data => this.status = data); // takeUntil is for unsubscribing when component is destroyed - protect from memory leak

Comment: I did what you said: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7dffny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I would suggest to do sth like that:
  destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  status = false;
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private _myService: MyserviceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._myService.serviceStatus
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('onButtonPress', response);
        this.status = response;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    this._myService.takeAction();
  }

Comment: the suggestion worked. Tweaked it a bit and it was good. thanks

Comment: Thank you a lot, now I got really clear the use for Subjects in rxjs.